# How to create XYZ vector tiles with an overlapping buffer between the tiles

Tags: openlayers

OpenLayers clips symbols and text at the edges of vector tiles:

[image: map with vector features]

I would like the features to be fully rendered, instead of being clipped.

According to [that discussion](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12567), clipping seems to be an expected behavior.

I have noticed that there is a [`renderBuffer`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/c7969f5255edd8cbe5ece89ab026fe0f6f69cef1/src/ol/layer/VectorTile.js#L45) option in the layer that is supposed to add a buffer around the tiles to not clip directly at the edges of the tiles, but it can only work if the tiles do have an overlapping buffer (see [this comment](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/12567#issuecomment-888499411)).

Therefore, I would like to produce vector tiles with an overlapping buffer. I am currently generating tiles in the XYZ format and I am not sure whether it is possible to have overlapping tiles. Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/c7969f5255edd8cbe5ece89ab026fe0f6f69cef1/src/ol/tilegrid/TileGrid.js#L455-L464), it seems OpenLayers strongly assumes that the tiles are adjacent, not overlapping.

Is it possible to describe a `TileGrid` containing tiles with an overlapping buffer? Otherwise, what are the tile formats that support an overlapping buffer?